# Translating C++ recursive floodfill implementation for 2D array without any loops, into Java?

Tags: java, c++, recursion, stack-overflow, flood-fill

I am trying to translate a recursive flood-fill implementation that doesn't use any loops. I keep getting a stack overflow error, and I'm not sure why. I have been trying to translate the C++ code [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flood-fill-algorithm-implement-fill-paint/).

How can I fix my Java translation of this code?

**C++ original code:**

```
// A recursive function to replace previous color 'prevC' at  '(x, y)'  
// and all surrounding pixels of (x, y) with new color 'newC' and 
void floodFillUtil(int screen[][N], int x, int y, int prevC, int newC) 
{ 
// Base cases 
if (x < 0 || x >= M || y < 0 || y >= N) 
    return; 
if (screen[x][y] != prevC) 
    return; 

// Replace the color at (x, y) 
screen[x][y] = newC; 

// Recur for north, east, south and west 
floodFillUtil(screen, x+1, y, prevC, newC); 
floodFillUtil(screen, x-1, y, prevC, newC); 
floodFillUtil(screen, x, y+1, prevC, newC); 
floodFillUtil(screen, x, y-1, prevC, newC); 
}
```

**my Java floodFill() method:**

```
public void floodFill(int[][] pic, int row, int col, int oldC, int newC) {

  // Base Cases
  if(row < 0 || col < 0 || row >= pic.length - 1 || col >= pic[row].length - 1) {
     return;
  }
  if(pic[row][col] != oldC) {
     return;
  }

  // recursion
  floodFill(pic, row++, col, oldC, newC);
  floodFill(pic, row--, col, oldC, newC);
  floodFill(pic, row, col++, oldC, newC);
  floodFill(pic, row, col--, oldC, newC);
}
```

Comment: There is no equivalent of `screen[x][y] = newC;` in the Java code

Comment: @TheDark I'm sorry, I told you it worked, but it doesn't do the entire array. it only seems to work for the node itself, and the nodes to the top, bottom, left, and right of it.

Comment: When you recurse, you are using suffix operators `row++`, etc.  Those increment AFTER use - so you are actually passing in the unchanged `row` value (not to mention changing the value on the following calls).   Use the row + 1 as you do in your C++..

Comment: @racraman This seems to help, but I am still not filling all of the connected nodes. Rather, now I seem to be filling three instead of two. Most of the nodes around the initial "fill-point" are not of the same int value.

Comment: Also in your base conditions, you should have either ">= N", or compare against "N -1".  By having both as in ">= N -1", you're missing out the upper bound.

Comment: @racraman Sorry, I had already removed those in my IDE, but I forgot to do it here. I have updated the question.

Comment: show how is pic populated

Comment: @racraman Sorry everyone, racraman's suggestions worked for me. I didn't think they worked because I mistyped it. I'm sorry for all the confusion with this question. I'm going to wait 24 hours for people who tried to help to post their own solutions if they want the points. Otherwise, I'll post my own solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to put the line `pic[row][col] = newC` in the program. Another problem was that I didn't know `variableName++` is a different command from `variableName + 1` so the recursion didn't work as expected. `variableName++` returns the value of `variableName` *before* it was incremented.

**This code allowed my program to work:**

```java
public void floodFill(int[][] pic, int row, int col, int oldC, int newC) {

  // Base Cases
  if(row < 0 || col < 0 || row >= pic.length || col >= pic[row].length) {
     return;
  }
  if(pic[row][col] != oldC) {
     return;
  }

  pic[row][col] = newC;

  // recursion
  floodFill(pic, row + 1, col, oldC, newC);
  floodFill(pic, row - 1, col, oldC, newC);
  floodFill(pic, row, col + 1, oldC, newC);
  floodFill(pic, row, col - 1, oldC, newC);
}
```